# reliable way to validate IBAN/BIC in java

Tags: java, banking

Does anyone know of a reliable way to validate International Bank Account Number (IBAN) and Bank Identifier Code (BIC) in java?

Comment: Rephrased the original question. I'm no longer using the dreadful word "library", which caused the question to be closed as off-topic

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These might be worth a look:

http://soastation.googlepages.com/iban-checkdigit-src.jar

http://developers.sun.com/docs/javacaps/designing/capsswftintprj.ghfyv.html

Comment: Brandon, your first link works fine (just downloads a jar file with no copyright etc, is this what you intended?)  The second link though, is broken.  Looks like Oracle doesn't like it much.

Answer (score 38):

Apache Commons Validator has IBAN validation (since version 1.4)

Home page: http://commons.apache.org/validator/

Javadoc: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/checkdigit/IBANCheckDigit.html

Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
  <version>1.7</version>
</dependency>
```

*Edit: Updated javadoc link.*

Comment: The correct link to the javadoc is:http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/javadocs/api-1.4.0/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/checkdigit/IBANCheckDigit.html

Answer (score 16):

Apache Commons Validator is good for IBAN validation, but lacks BBAN structure validation (as specified in [IBAN registry](https://www.swift.com/resource/iban-registry-pdf)).

I have just released a library, named jbanking, that might suits your need. It contains routines for both IBAN and BIC validation. You can find it on github (https://github.com/marcwrobel/jbanking).

But note that you cannot have a reliable BIC / IBAN validation without using the [IBAN Plus Directory](http://swiftref.swift.com/iban-plus) (formely known as the [BICplusIBAN Directory](http://www.swift.com/products/bicplusiban_directory)) and the [Bank directory Plus](http://swiftref.swift.com/bank-directory-plus) (formely known as the [BIC directory](http://www.swift.com/products/bic_directory)). Both are provided and regularly updated by SWIFT which is the BIC / IBAN registrar. Unfortunately those directories are not available for free.

Answer (score 5):

iban4j might be good choice for IBAN validation.

home page: https://github.com/arturmkrtchyan/iban4j

Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.iban4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>iban4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hello, I just reviewed and finally decided to use your library. Nice work and simple API. Many thanks for sharing!

Comment: what should be my motivation NOT to use Apache IBAN Validator, if I only want to validate IBAN?

Comment: Above library is outdated, another alternative is https://github.com/barend/java-iban

Answer (score 1):

This is a library of utilities to assist with developing banking functionality.
https://github.com/marcwrobel/jbanking

Answer (score 0):

This library provides an IBAN class supporting BBAN structure validation.

http://www.jdtaus.org/ISO-13616/current/index.html